# How can I resolve the 'unauthorized' error when pushing Docker image to hub.docker.com from GitLab pipeline?

Tags: gitlab, pipeline, unauthorized

Error while pushing an image to hub.docker.com from GitLab pipeline

CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE is set to `index.docker.io/<myusername>/<myimagename>`
CI_REGISTRY is set as index.docker.io

I tried the above values with docker.io too.
But either way I land into this error.

```
Successfully built 31aeefb313cc
$ docker tag $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:latest $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:1.0
$ docker login -u "$CI_REGISTRY_USER" -p "$CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD" $CI_REGISTRY[0;m
Login Succeeded
$ docker push $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:1.0

The push refers to a repository [docker.io/[MASKED]/<image_name>]
d3bd94f6d15e: Preparing
91bef4c45fc9: Preparing
ea5c23c3dd62: Preparing
b6eeeecd7263: Preparing
cc2f8f3cc5db: Preparing
a8fb89efd40d: Preparing
425f0def498e: Preparing
9733ccc39513: Preparing
a8fb89efd40d: Waiting
425f0def498e: Waiting
9733ccc39513: Waiting
unauthorized: authentication required
```

All the variables are set in CI/CD

Following is the pipeline code I have.

```
 script:
    - docker version
    - docker build -t $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:latest .
    - docker tag $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:latest $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:1.0
    - docker login -u "$CI_REGISTRY_USER" -p "$CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD" $CI_REGISTRY
    - docker push $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:1.0
```

**UPDATE**
I solved issue with the following changes.
Contrary to a lot of messages here and blogs I read the solution is a bit different but worked for me.

The pipeline code is as follows

```
docker build -t $CI_REGISTRY_USER/<image_name>:tag .
docker login -u "$CI_REGISTRY_USER" -p "$CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD" $CI_REGISTRY
docker push $CI_REGISTRY_USER/<image_name>:tag
```

Comment: You need to use `docker login`.  Your CI environment will need to have the credentials stored in environment variables, then just add a line to your script, such as `docker login -u=$USERNAME -p=$PASSWORD`

Comment: CI_REGISTRY_USER,  CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD are environment variables for registry user and password set in CI/CD variables of GitLab project settings.

Comment: Yeah, it doesn't matter what you call the variables; you just have to execute a login first.  It looks like you've got it going.